# Redshift. How to create a custom hashed id column in default?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

how to create a automatic hashed id column in Redshift?

i want to get automatically id column like this:

```
select murmur3_32_hash('a' || 'a') as id, 'a' as col1, 'a' as col2
```

after using this insert statement:

```
insert into test_table (col1, col2) values ('a', 'a');
```

[image]

I tried to create table like this:

```
create table test_table
(
    id varchar DEFAULT murmur3_32_hash(col1 || col2),
    col1 varchar(10),
    col2 varchar(10)
);
```

But i receive this error:

```
[42P10] ERROR: cannot use column references in default expression
```

What alternatives i could use? Input variables should be:

1. Table name
2. List of unique columns

Answer (score 0):

Per the Redshift CREATE TABLE documentation:

> “DEFAULT default_expr - Clause that assigns a default data value for the
> column. The data type of default_expr must match the data type of the
> column. The DEFAULT value must be a variable-free expression.
> Subqueries, cross-references to other columns in the current table,
> and user-defined functions aren't allowed.”

Your answer is that you cannot do this as a table default.